# how to store into an array line token from text file?

Tags: java

I have a text file with the following:

```
First Name : Javier Last Name : Smith E-mail : smith@.com Password: jsmith Date of Birth: Jan 1, 1987

First Name : Jade Last Name : Tux E-mail : nicholson@.com Password: jade123 Date of Birth: Jan 1, 1954

First Name : Bruce Last Name : Porto E-mail : bruce_porto@.com Password: br11 Date of Birth: Feb 25, 1946
```

I want to get the strings Javier, Smith, smith@.com, jsmith on the first line and so on and store these strings in a arraylist of type person (string, tring, string, string) and do the same with each line.

Here is my code so far:

```
try
{
    searchUser = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/users.txt")).useDelimiter(":");
    String storeFirst = "", storeLast = "", storeEmail = "", storePassword = "";
    usersArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String line = null;

    while(searchUser.hasNextLine())
    {
        line = searchUser.nextLine();
            storeFirst = searchUser.next();
        storeLast = searchUser.next();
        storeEmail = searchUser.next();
        storePassword = searchUser.next();
        line = searchUser.nextLine();

        usersArray.add(new Person(storeFirst, storeLast, storeEmail, storePassword));

        for(Person ae : usersArray)
        {
            System.out.println(ae.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(storeFirst);
        System.out.println(storeLast);
        System.out.println(storeEmail);
        System.out.println(storePassword);

    }
    searchUser.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more information on the exact problem your having with the current code and what you'd like help on? Currently it looks a little bit like "please finish my assignment." (If this _is_ an assignment, please state this in your question.)

Comment: this is an individual project for my CS class... everybody tried to come up with a different project.. so i created this one. what i am trying to do is a library database. so the program will ask you if you are a member of library, if you are not a member, you register and enter information, if you are a member, you log in.

Comment: so what i am trying to do is to store all the library users into a text file and when user tries to log in, the program will search through the text file and if user email and password matches with the emails and password on the text file, then a code saying "welcome" will appear on screen. so what i am trying to do is store the text file into an arraylist so it is easier to find if user email and password match!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while loop to read and populate the array first and then have print loop outside as:

```
 while(searchUser.hasNextLine()){
  //read the tokens first ignoring tag tokens
  searchUser.next();//ignore "First Name"
  storeFirst = searchUser.next().split(" ")[0];//split the 3 words and take 1st
  storeLast = searchUser.next().split(" ")[0];//split the 2 words and take 1st
  storeEmail = searchUser.next().split(" ")[0];//split the 2 words and take 1st
  storePassword = searchUser.next().split(" ")[0];//split the 2 words and take 1st
  //read and ignore remaining text including the new line character in the end
  searchUser.nextLine();

  Person person = new Person(storeFirst, storeLast, storeEmail, storePassword);
  usersArray.add(person);
}
```

Now have the print code as:

```
 for(Person ae : usersArray){
   System.out.println(ae.toString());
 }
```

Comment: thank you @YogendraSingh! it's working.. now, my problem is that when the scanner reaches the end of file, it outputs a 'NoSuchElementElementException'... i don't know what i'm missing here!

Comment: @user1889004 You may be having a blank line in the end of the file. The above code assumes that if there is any line, it has all the tokens. To resolve the issue, try one of the below. 1. Remove the blank line fro mthe end of the file. 2. Change the first line in the above code as `String firstNameTag = searchUser.next(); if(firstNameTag.isEmpty()){ break;}` to break the loop if the line is blank. If it oesn't fix your issue, let me know.

Comment: thanks again @yogendra snigh.. after a long time figuring out what was wrong, i found out that there was blanks after all the contacts.. so, it was returning this exception error! now, it's working as it should :)! thanks again1